# Firebase: Checking whether a value already exists in any of the child nodes or not

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to find whether a email (entered by the user) already exists in the my Firebase child node or not.

How do i check it?

MY PROGRAM:

```
String email = "emailEnteredByUser@gmail.com";
Query check = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("student").child(RANDOM_ID).orderByChild("email").equalTo(email);
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            if(snapshot.exists())
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Email already exists!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Email doesn't exists!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    };
    check.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

note: i'm using RANDOM_ID just for the reference, it'll be randomly generated id's

[image: Here's my Firebase database]

Comment: `if(snapshot.exists())` the else is only going to be the opposite of this so it is not ncessary to call `if (!snapshot.exists())`

Comment: Please **never** leave `onCancelled` empty. At its minimum it should be `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run a query on that path, Firebase checks the condition for each child directly under that path. Since you run the query on `/student/$RANDOM_ID`, it then checks each child node under that (so `email`, `id`, etc) whether **they** have a property `email` with the given value. And since there is no `/student/$RANDOM_ID/email/email`, the query doesn't match any nodes.

The correct query to check whether any direct child node of `student` has a `email` property with the given value, is:

```
Query check = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("student").orderByChild("email").equalTo(email);
```